# Show variable value with in jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am sorry if it is a newbie question, but I have searched alot on internet but couldn't found a solution. Problem is that I want to show a variable value within jquery code, my jquery code is down here,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $alt = $('.main-img').attr('alt');
    $('.main-img').after("<div class='slide_title'>$alt</div>");
});
```

now problem is that I want to show variable alt value in , thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat the string properly...

Like this:

```
$('.main-img').after('<div class="slide_title">' + $alt + '</div>');
```

or as per Satpal Solution....

it works like

```
var a = "" + your variable +""
```

but in your code you have all string

```
$('.main-img').after('<div class="slide_title"> $alt </div>');
```

so `$alt` is considered as `string` not a `variable`.

You can put html tag or text or etc which you want before or after your custom variable.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate variable while creating HTML string.

```
$('.main-img').after("<div class='slide_title'>" + $alt + "</div>");
```

Comment: thnx mate for giving your time.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way, if the variable's value may include characters like `<` which are special in HTML, is to use the `text` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var main = $('.main-img');
    $("<div class='slide_title'></div>")
        .text(main.attr('alt'))
        .insertAfter(main);
});
```

If you **want** to use HTML in the variable's text, then either string concatenation or the `html` function:

String concat:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var main = $('.main-img');
    $("<div class='slide_title'>" + main.attr('alt') + "</div>")
        .insertAfter(main);
});
```

`html`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var main = $('.main-img');
    $("<div class='slide_title'></div>")
        .html(main.attr('alt'))
        .insertAfter(main);
});
```

Comment: thanx mate for answering, I got answer from your question but you made it little complex, I need a simple solution like given by Akki619, but still I am very thankful to you.